# how to send msgs from mobile to web server through ussd?

Tags: java, c++, c, ussd

I want to send a msg to a web server from  a mobile phone through USSD. Is it possible and if yes how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You will need to use an [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway).

Comment: thnx,but can u describe in brief as to how can I do it through SMS gateway,actually I m not gettin the actual flow for it,so plz reply if possible.